# How to use gdalwarp in Spyder?

Tags: raster, shapefile, gdal, clip, spyder

I cliped images based on gdalwarp in cmd, the code is as following:

```
gdalwarp -q -cutline G:\2016.06.MOD\MOD02\5Clip\Clip_Image_Shp\Clip_Image.shp -tr 1000.0 1000.0 -of GTiff G:\2016.06.MOD\MOD02\3Resample_1000m_ProjectionC\20160628_1905_reflectance_georef_Resample_ProjectionC.tif G:\2016.06.MOD\MOD02\5Clip\20160628_1905_Clip.tif -crop_to_cutline
```

Now, I want to clip images based on gdalwarp in Spyder, but I don't know how to change the code in Spyder? Could you give me some advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can execute a command in a subshell using [`os.system()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system). For example:

```
os.system('gdalwarp -q -cutline G:\2016.06.MOD\MOD02\5Clip\Clip_Image_Shp\Clip_Image.shp -tr 1000.0 1000.0 -of GTiff G:\2016.06.MOD\MOD02\3Resample_1000m_ProjectionC\20160628_1905_reflectance_georef_Resample_ProjectionC.tif G:\2016.06.MOD\MOD02\5Clip\20160628_1905_Clip.tif -crop_to_cutline')
```

Otherwise, you can use the GDAL Python API. A good place to find examples is the [GDAL/OGR Cookbook](https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook). In your case, the [Clip a GeoTiff with Shapefile](https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/raster_layers.html#clip-a-geotiff-with-shapefile) example should be what your after.

Comment: Thanks for your solution,I have tried it as you said, but I didn't make it.

Comment: What method did you try? What errors are you receiving?

Comment: I used os.system function as your example.I cannot get the correct answer.All code is:                                                                                
`>from osgeo import gdal
>import os, sys

>os.system('gdalwarp -q -cutline G:\2016.06.MOD\MOD02\5Clip\Clip_Image_Shp\Clip_Image.shp -tr 1000.0 1000.0 -of GTiff G:\2016.06.MOD\MOD02\3Resample_1000m_ProjectionC\20160628\20160628_1905_reflectance_georef_Resample_ProjectionC.tif G:\20160628_1905_Clip.tif -crop_to_cutline')`

Comment: The errors I received is C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL\gdalplugins\gdal HDF4Image.dll is not valid Win32 application program.